# Files in Desktop cannot be edited in macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, catalina, desktop

I cannot open, change, edit, write, or read any of the files in my desktop.

I have pictures on my desktop but when I attempt to open them, this error appears: "The file “FileName” couldn’t be opened."

Same with documents and other text files.

This includes files in subdirectories underneath Desktop as well.

All the permissions of Desktop and read and write, in terminal I can move and edit text files, but I cannot do it within the UI itself.

Model Name: MacBook Pro.
Model Identifier:   MacBookPro14,1.
Processor Name: Dual-Core Intel Core i5. 
Processor Speed: 2.3 GHz.
macOS Catalina 10.15.1

Comment: Is the macOS account  you're using (with respect to the GUI) an administrator account ?  And is it the same account you're using in _Terminal_, or are you logged in there as a different user, or do you invoke `sudo` at any point ? If you select a file and view its info (`Cmd-I`) what are the permissions settings (scroll to bottom) ? Have you tried changing them ?

Comment: I am an administrator both on the GUI and in terminal. The permissions are Read and Write and even when I `chmod 755` the desktop directory and everything in it this error still arises. I never used `sudo`.

Comment: And did you look at the permissions in _Finder_ ?  You may be using an administrator account, but you didn't confirm that the accounts are the same one for both _Finder_ and _Terminal_, and whether the _Findet_ account had permissions. Being admin doesn't imply this. You could also examine the attributes using `ls -l@` in _Terminal_

Comment: Voting to close: OP has not provided sufficient detail for any accurate answer. If he hasn't solved it by now, it's not his main concern. It's not a useful post for anyone else with similar symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your home folder and highlight the desktop folder, then press Cmd-I. Untick the "lock" box if it is ticked.